# How to remove last new line from stream from command line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, newline

I have command line this:

```bsh
xclip -o -sel clip | sed -e 's/^ *"\(.*\)"+\?/\1/g' | tr -d '\n' |
    sed -e 's/.\{,55\}/"&"+\n/g' |
    sed -e "2,$ s/^/$(seq 22 | xargs -I{} echo -n ' ')/" |
    sed -e '$ s/+$//' | xclip -sel clip
```

which format string in source code (I use it to format long string in javascript file - 55 and 22 are harcoded width and indent)

```
var foo = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"+
          ". Nulla sed dolor nisl, in suscipit justo. Donec a enim"+
          " et est porttitor semper at vitae augue. Proin at nulla"+
          " at dui mattis mattis. Nam a volutpat ante. Aliquam con"+
          "sequat dui eu sem convallis ullamcorper."
```

but when I copy past code inside parentheses `var foo = foo.bar()` I got this

```
var foo = foo.bar("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"+
                  ". Nulla sed dolor nisl, in suscipit justo. Donec a enim"+
                  " et est porttitor semper at vitae augue. Proin at nulla"+
                  " at dui mattis mattis. Nam a volutpat ante. Aliquam con"+
                  "sequat dui eu sem convallis ullamcorper."
)
```

New line after last quote, not the big deal but anybody know how can I remove that last new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, using `awk`. Setting `RS` (record separator) to the empty string tells `awk` to treat blank lines (i.e. two consecutive `\n`) as record separators. Setting `FS` to `\n` causes `awk` to take `\n` as field separators instead of white-space. (Setting `RS` to the empty string also causes `\n` to be used as a field separator, but we want to avoid having other whitespace recognized.) Finally, we set `OFS` (output field separator) to be the string we want between lines (closing quote, plus, linefeed, 22 spaces, opening quote) and setting `ORS` (output record separator) to an empty string causes `awk` to not write any linefeed at the end.

I use `fold` to split the lines into 55-byte chunks instead of sed, partly because it seems tidier, and partly because, unlike `sed`, it doesn't add a new line at the end of the input if there wasn't one to start with.

The seemingly redundant `$1=$1` causes `awk` to recreate `$0`, which has the effect of using `OFS` as the output field separator between the fields. Otherwise, it is only used to separate separate print arguments.

The first and last line are unchanged from the OP.

```
xclip -o -sel clip | sed -e 's/^ *"\(.*\)"+\?/\1/g' | tr -d '\n' |
fold -b -w55 |
awk -vFS=$'\n' -vOFS="$(printf '"+\n%22s"' '')" \
    -vRS='' -vORS='' \
    '{$1=$1; print "\"" $0 "\""}' |
xclip -sel clip
```

Comment: Great, I never use awk a lot, need to take a closer look at it. And thanks for `fold` I was searching for this command but thought it's called `cols` or something.